# Gayelord Hauser brewers yeast

Tags: yeast, alcohol-content

What is the maximum alcohol content of Gayelord Hauser brewers yeast? I have seen it at the grocery store and am wondering what I can do with it.

Comment: This question should be asked in the homebrew forum, not in the beer forum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe nutritional supplement yeast will ferment because it is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Supplements are not good ingredients as they are processed. Rather buy real yeast and brew proper beer.

homebrew.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for this type of question.